# Purpose of extra holes for pins or Arduino clone

Tags: arduino-uno, pins, clones

I bought this Arduino clone recently and it has lot of extra holes for pins, but some of them I don't know what they do. There was no instruction manual that came with it. Here's a picture of it, I added a red rectangle around the ones I don't know. (4 pins with X1, SCL/SDA, AREF and blank pin in the bottom)
[image: Arduino uno clone unknown pins]

I thought I could use the pins SCL SDA 5V GND with my I2C LCD Display because the names of the pins are the same on it. Could it work? Usually I use analog pins to connect the display, does that mean that by using it some analog pins will be used indirectly? I didn't try connecting it because I don't want it to break.

[image]

What do these pins do?

Comment: I bought [this one](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/NEW-ATmega328P-CH340G-UNO-R3-Board-USB-Cable-for-Arduino-DIY-MC-/161977675428?hash=item25b69f2ea4:g:XnMAAOSwzgRWwDiw)

Comment: I'v had the same question and searched for a manual... And where is the manual?

Comment: For the Arduino clone? Should be the same as standard Arduinos.

Answer (score 3):

It's what they say they are.

SDA/SCL are I2C - what used to be A4/A5 on the old footprint. On the '328 based boards those are directly linked to the A4/A5 pins.

The blank pin isn't used. The 5V next to it is actually mislabelled and should be labelled "IOREF".

AREF has been there since the very first Arduino boards.

It's the standard "R3" Uno footprint, plus some extra breakouts for the I2C in different forms (probably to go with specific I2C devices they also sell).

All of that is on the [Uno's product page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/main/arduinoBoardUno) if you'd care to read it some time...

The ones by the cheap Chinese USB interface chip will be something to do with that. Maybe RTS/CTS broken out on a header. You can ignore those - they are of no interest at all. In fact, just looking in their direction has a good chance of breaking the USB interface chip. Stay well away.

Comment: Does IOREF sets the voltage on I/O pins?

Comment: IOREF tells a shield what voltage the main board runs at.

Comment: It's all in the manual. I seriously suggest you read it. At the moment you're just making a fool of yourself asking such basic questions.

Comment: Would that make you happy?

Comment: If you were happy?